# How can I have a one-way synonym in Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying  to implement one way synonym or one way thesaurus(as in Endeca) in Solr. Where I search for camcorder I get result for camera also but not vice versa. I tried adding following in Synonyms.txt but seems to be not working as it is giving weird results:

camcorder => camera

And my schema.xml is:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100"  multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ClassicFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ClassicFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: you forgot to post your schema.xml also give us more info about what results are you getting and what are you expecting. P.s `writing require the answer asap` won't give you the answer asap

Comment: if without this configuration I search separately i get say 20 and 30 results respectively. In one way thesaurus search for camcordershould give me 50 results and search ffor camera should still give me 30 results.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you were looking for is:

```
camcorder => camera, camcorder
```

If you don't include camcorder on the right side, camcorder won't return any results if you search for "camcorder".

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only expanding synonyms when you're indexing (where you have the SynonymFilter defined), `camcorder` will be changed to `camera` for each document on the way in. When you don't have the same expansion taking place when querying, Solr will still search for `camcorder` (as there is no SynonymFilter defined for the query analysis chain). There is no `camcorder` token in the index, so there will be no hit.

You'll have to expand synonyms when querying as well as when indexing to achieve what you want with one-way synonyms.

Comment: I did changes as per your answer. But still I ma getting same number of results. If without synonym configuration(camcorder => camera), I search separately i get say 20 and 30 results respectively. In one way synonym the search for camcorder should give me 50 results and search for camera should still give me 30 results.

Comment: If that's what you want, then you want to rewrite `camera` to `camera`, `camcorder` when you're indexing, not the other way around. That way any document containing camera will be associated with both camera and camcorder, and camcorders will only be associated with camcorders.